# SQL Server 2014 trigger with date constraint

Tags: sql-server, date, triggers

I have the below code that doesn't work because it doesn't recognize the column from the table

Code:

```
create trigger cerinta1 
on Factura
for insert 
as
    if YEAR(DataFactura) < 2010
    begin
        raiserror ('Can t add the row!',15,2)
    end
```

Comment: What columns are in `Factura` table?

Comment: A column constraint would be a better approach. Triggers are a topic more suited to someone with tsql experience.

Comment: You should add that as an answer @Smor, it's a much better idea than the trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When referencing a column, you still need to say what object it is part of. On it's own `DataFactura` means nothing. Try:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.cerinta1
ON dbo.Factura
FOR INSERT
AS
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE DataFactura < '20100101') --Rather than using YEAR, pass an actual date
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Can''t add data before 2010!', 15, 2); --A more descriptive error is better.
    END;
```